# How can I retrieve data stored in my database and display it as a qr code?,

Tags: javascript, android, qr-code, barcode

So I am in the middle of developing an android application using android studio for delivery drivers.

How can I retrieve data stored in my database and display it as a barcode? , preferably  a QR code. The purpose of this is so the barcode can be scanned.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing a database directly from JavaScript is generally considered very risky, as it will give your clients direct access. It is considered much safer to use a server side language such as PHP, Java, .Net, etc... However, assuming you are aware of the risks, and it isn't a concern, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser) post goes into good detail on how to set up a database connection to a SQL server through JavaScript

[How to connect to SQL Server database from JavaScript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser)

In terms of then generating a QRCode, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196798/javascript-api-for-generating-qr-codes) post offers a few good APIs for generating QR codes in Javascript.

[javascript API for generating QR codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196798/javascript-api-for-generating-qr-codes)

Hope this helps!